# Как отсортировать список

Tags: python, list

`id чата, id сообщения, Тип пользователя, id пользователя, время создания сообщения.`

```
[['64263900413738', '11424785046', 'User', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '60ec125d672e29b84b6d3c56', 1635196844],
['64263900413738', '11424786195', 'User', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '60ec125d672e29b84b6d3c56', 1635196850],
['64263900413738', '11424800612', 'User', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '60ec125d672e29b84b6d3c56', 1635196929],
['64263900413738', '11424815490', 'User', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '60ec125d672e29b84b6d3c56', 1635197012],
['64263900413738', '11424825813', 'User', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '60ec125d672e29b84b6d3c56', 1635197070],
['64263900413738', '11424837469', 'User', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '60ec125d672e29b84b6d3c56', 1635197133],
['64263900413738', '11424838783', 'Admin', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '5077390', 1635197141],
['64263900413738', '11424874244', 'User', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '60ec125d672e29b84b6d3c56', 1635197336],
['64263900413738', '11424896431', 'Admin', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '5077390', 1635197453],
['64263900413738', '11428189485', 'Admin', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '5033600', 1635227238],
['64263900413738', '11428286370', 'User', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '60ec125d672e29b84b6d3c56', 1635228109],
['64263900413738', '11428294111', 'User', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '60ec125d672e29b84b6d3c56', 1635228152],
['64263900413738', '11428300223', 'Admin', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '5033600', 1635228187],
['64263900413738', '11429435921', 'Admin', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '5033600', 1635235200],
['64263900413738', '11431724157', 'Admin', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '5033600', 1635245088],
['64263900413738', '11435056174', 'Admin', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '5033600', 1635256604],
['64263900413738', '11438123689', 'User', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '60ec125d672e29b84b6d3c56', 1635265580],
['64263900413738', '11438132222', 'User', 'https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/inbox/inbox/conversation/64263900413738', '60ec125d672e29b84b6d3c56', 1635265606]]
```

у меня есть вот такой список, это ответы на сообщения в чате.
Каждая строка это информация о конкретном сообщении.

Нужно получить время ответа админа на сообщение юзера.
Временем ответа считать разницу между сообщением юзера и первым сообщением админа.

При условии что ответом на первое сообщение юзера будет первое сообщение от админа. То есть нужно получить пары как на скрине.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Время реакции нужно считать от сообщения юзера.

Моя идея состоит в следующем:
Вначале отсортировать этот список, чтобы получить пары списков user-admin , а затем уже из времени админа вычесть время юзера.

Подскажите как нужно отсортировать этот список чтобы получились нужные пары.

Comment: Тут лучше всего загнать таблицу в `Pandas`, но код мне пока некогда писать

Comment: Так себе идея такое считать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, и нужно найти разницу во времени между первым вопросом пользователя и первым ответом админа, принимая во внимание, что вопросы-ответы идут по порядку и серия начинается с вопроса, можно попробовать сделать так:

```
import pandas as pd
lst = # тут ваш длинющий список

df = pd.DataFrame(lst) # превращаем список в датафрейм
diffs = df.loc[df[2] != df[2].shift(1)] # выделяем группы "первый вопрос
                                        # юзера- первый ответ админа"
diffs = diffs.loc[:diffs[diffs.iloc[:,2]=="Admin"].index[-1]] # удаляем последние
                                        # данные о вопросах, если на них не было ответов
res = (diffs[5].values[1::2] - diffs[5].values[::2]).tolist() # попарно вычитаем
```

res:

```
[297, 117, 78]
```

Answer (score 1):

а такой подход чем не нравится?

```
data = [
    ['12', '23', 'User'],
    ['23', '34', 'Admin'],
    ['12', '34', 'User'],
    ['32', '23', 'Admin'],
    ['12', '12', 'PC'],
]

data.sort(key=lambda obj: obj[2])

print(data)
```

или надо что-то еще дополнительно?